# Logging multiple error message in the TRY...CATCH when doing BACKUP DATABASE

Tags: sql-server, backup, error-handling, logging

When I try below:

```
backup database not_existing_db to disk = 'E:\Backup\not_existing_db.bak'
```

SSMS shows two error messages:

```
Msg 911, Level 16, State 11, Line 22
Database 'not_existing_db' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.

Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 22
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

When I try to encapsulate it into TRY...CATCH block like below:

```
begin try
    backup database not_existing_db to disk = 'E:\Backup\not_existing_db.bak'
end try
begin catch
    select ERROR_MESSAGE()
end catch
```

error_message() only shows second error which is not informative at all

I want to find a way to log both messages, so most informative error message (first) could be send by email to DBA

Please help to find out how to do that

Comment: Also, see related item on Connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/746979/try-catch-construct-catches-last-error-only